# SecureSocial 2 with play 2 framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, google-oauth, securesocial

I am trying to use SecureSocial 2. When I trying to use existing account e.g. Google it gives me error:

```
Error: invalid_client

scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/authenticate/google
state=736c4f77-14e8-4cde-ac61-7df8796067ba
client_id=your_client_id
```

Please tell me what should I do to sort it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you properly configure SecureSocial through the config file (https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/java/demo/conf/securesocial.conf) ?

Comment: my **securesocial.conf** file is exactly same as on github, do I need to make any changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register your app on Google, which will provide a client id and a client secret.

Take a look at this doc from Google: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please tell me where should I put redirect URI. I am getting error **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**

Comment: what did u change the redirect uri to ?

Comment: @gabhi, did you figure out what the redirect url should be?

Comment: @teo i changed redirect uri in the google api console to  http://localhost:9000/authenticate/google